# sqlite update a tuple

Tags: android, sqlite

I was trying to update a row in sqlite db, but it gives syntax error. I think I'm missing something but I can't see it. Maybe you can help me.

Update code:

```
 public void updateEntry(String oldname,String name,String mail, String phone,String adres)
     {
     ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
     args.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
     args.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, mail);
     args.put(COLUMN_PHONE, phone);
     args.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, adres);
     sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, args,COLUMN_NAME + "=" + oldname, null);
     }
```

Calling update (By the way t,t2,t3,t4 are EditTexts)

```
 mySQLiteAdapter.updateEntry(isim, t.getText().toString(), t2.getText().toString(), t3.getText().toString(), t4.getText().toString());
```

Errors

```
07-30 11:34:56.487: E/AndroidRuntime(1990): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "smith": syntax error: , while compiling: UPDATE MY_TABLE SET Name=?, Phone=?, Email=?, Address=? WHERE Name=john smith
```

First I thought, I didn't give any address or phone as string, but I printed them and I see the correct values. Any idea where my fault is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have not escaped `oldname` string which contains `john smith`.

use `sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, args,COLUMN_NAME + "='" + oldname + "'", null);`

or use

```
String whereClause = COLUMN_NAME + "=?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {oldname};
sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, args, whereClause, whereArgs, null);
```

Comment: ooh I used " " instead of ' ', that's why I didn't try ' ' again. Anyway thank you it worked.